# Vertically align divs side by side at the bottom of their parent div

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to place multiple divs at the bottom of the page located within a 0 height div so that the container div doesn't cover part of the page and thus intercept any mouse click events.  As of right now, the divs only start from the parent div line(0 height parent) and go downwards instead of upwards.  Essentially, I am attempting to replicate the way facebook has its instant chat messenger set up while being as cross browser compatible as it can be, however, everything I have been able to find online relates to single elements, stacked elements (on top of each other) or use various methods like `display:table-cell` or `display:flex` which are not cross-browser compatible with older versions of IE.

If you who are reading this believes that it would be little of a problem compatibility wise(as in too few people use IE version X and prior), then you can throw the compatibility issue out the door (as long as it remains cross-browser).

Here is a rather crappy attempt at making a visual(couldn't find a line that would stand at the top of a text block so assume when the image stops that it is where the page would end).

```
______________
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|            |
|       ___  |
|  __  |   | |
| |  | |   | |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- Display the items as `inline-block` to stack them horizontally.
- Use `vertical-align: bottom` to align their bottom edge to the bottom of the line box.
- Consider using `white-space: nowrap` to force them to stay in a single line box.
- Place them inside an absolutely positioned inner wrapper with `bottom: 0`, i.e. placed at the bottom of its containing block.
- Place that inner wrapper in a relatively positioned outer wrapper.

```css
#outer-wrapper {
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 70px;
}
#inner-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.bigger.item {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="inner-wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="bigger item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just realized, how would I set this to be `position:fixed;`?  I need this to be super-glued to the bottom of the screen just like facebook chat.

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck Then use `position: fixed; bottom: 0` [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vt6jbtde/). But if you take it out of the flow, I don't see the point of `height: 0`.

Comment: I figured out what my problem was - the `#inner-wrapper` element was constricting itself to min width whenever I set the `#outer-wrapper` to `position:fixed` which caused the two items to stack on top of each other like block elements.  Thanks again mate.

Comment: @LoganHasbrouck Yes, fixed and absolute positions use the shrink-to-fit width algorithm. You can force the width to be something bigger. Or prevent line breaks with `white-space: pre`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer to Oriol. He/she left out the position:right on the absolutely positioned container but it's 99% the same as what I would do.

Demo:
http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/YyOaBo

- Create a relatively positioned container with the majority of your content
- Place an absolutely positioned container within the first container
- Create two inline-block items lined up together

HTML:

```
<div class="master-box">
  <div class="bottom-box-container">
    <div class="bottom-box-1">
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-box-2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.master-box {
  background-color: #b3d9ff;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  width: 800px;
}

.bottom-box-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.bottom-box-1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #ffedb3;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 200px;
}

.bottom-box-2 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #feb3ff;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 200px;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  width: 200px;
}
```